# How to store some part of string in another string

Tags: java, command-line

After executing command I am getting output as 
**(1036) "General Project"**
I Stored this output in one string variable.
I want to store **"General Project"** as output in other string variable
How can I do this?

Thank You

Comment: Look at String class and it's substring method.

Comment: read `String` handling in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Str = "(1036)\"General Project\"";
    String[] arr =Str.split("\\)");
    String s = arr[arr.length-1];
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do the simple thing which you are looking for.
Best approach: Read of String Operations in Java

Following are just *some* ways to achieve what you need:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String output1 = "(1036) \"General Project\"";
    String output2 = output1.split("\\) ")[1];
    String output3 = output1.substring(output1.indexOf("\""));;     

    System.out.println(output1);
    System.out.println(output2);
    System.out.println(output3);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in that way:

```
String str="(1036) \"General Project\"";
String str2=str.substring(str.indexOf("\""));
System.out.println(str2); // Output: "General Project"
```

I hope it helps.